# Is it appropriate to ask more details in a question asked years ago which was not even my question?

Tags: discussion

So I wanted to ask a question but it was already explained and answered earlier however I want to ask further as a new question would be a duplicate.So is it appropriate to ask on a question active years ago?

Comment: Additional rationale: similar to requesting information about parts you don't understand, it is perfectly fine to refer to an existing question and ask for more details on a specified part you'd like to see elaborated.